# Installing Zend Server CE via Puppet

Tags: zend-framework, puppet

I need to install Zend Server CE with PHP 5.2 on my debian stack via puppet. Can anyone help how should manifest look like. Install instruction are available here http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/zend-server.htm#deb_installation.htm

Thanks. Jaro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a puppet "module". It's available here https://github.com/NoStressCommerceCZ/virtualdev/tree/master/basic-box/puppet/modules/zendserverce and installs zend server ce 5.2 and allows you to create a virtual host.

**Update**:
https://github.com/NoStressCommerceCZ/virtualdev-module-puppet-zendserverce

Answer (score 0):

Puppet module [puppet-zendserver](https://github.com/TrafeX/puppet-zendserver) by TrafeX on GitHub.